# SQL View to find missing values, should be simple

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

I have two tables with a common id,
table1 has a task numbers column and table2 has documents column
each task can have multiple documents. I'm trying to find all task numbers that don't have a specific document

Fake data:

```
SELECT * FROM table1
id  tasknumber
1   3210-012
2   3210-022
3   3210-032

SELECT * FROM table2
id  document
1   revision1
1   SB
1   Ref
2   revision1
2   Ref
3   revision1
3   SB
```

But how would I find tasknumbers which don't have a document named SB?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: LEFT JOIN and null check (on right relation) or JOIN .. GROUP BY .. HAVING COUNT are two methods. Could also use an EXCEPT, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT t1.tasknumber
FROM   table1 t1
LEFT   JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.id = t1.id AND t2.document = 'SB'
WHERE  t2.id IS NULL;
```

There are basically four techniques:

- [Select rows which are not present in other table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19363481/select-rows-which-are-not-present-in-other-table/19364694#19364694)

Answer (score 1):

```
select t1.tasknumber from table1 t1
where not exists 
     (select 1 from table2 t2 where t1.id = t2.id and t2.document = 'SB')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select
    tasknumber
from 
    table1
where
    not exists (select 1
                  from table2
                 where table1.id = table2.id
                       and table2.document = 'SB');
```

or

```
select
    tasknumber
from 
    table1
where
    id not in (select id
                 from table2 
                where document = 'SB');
```

Comment: Closing parentheses missing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
SELECT TASKNUMBER 
FROM TABLE1
WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT ID FROM TABLE 2 where document = 'SB')
```

Comment: that 'and' at the end is unnecessary, but thanks that works great

Comment: @Amireza is it so hard to edit the answer so it can actually run without errors?

Comment: Sorry thanks I eddited it

Comment: @mrplow: You picked the least favorable solution. `NOT IN` is generally slowest and fails if `NULL` is involved.